# Dynamically change new folder name if folder with same name already exists

Tags: vbscript

Is there an way to dynamically change a new folder name if a folder with the same name already exists? For example, if I were to create a new file using `fso.CreateFolder`, would there be any way for the script to check for the folder and add an extra character, e.g from ("example") to ("example a"). I realize that I could use a file name from a variable and add characters like so:

```
dim filename
filename = ("example")
folderexists = fso.FolderExists(filename)

if (folderexists) then
fso.CreateFolder(filename + "a")
else
fso.CreateFolder(filename)
endif
```

but this would only work once, and after that would just continue to create and overwrite (filename + "a"). I would like the script to be able to detect, so for example:

```
first folder = (filename)
second folder = (filename + "a")
Third folder = (filename + "aa")
fourth folder = (filename + "aaa")
```

and so forth.

Comment: Append the date/time to your filename. It will never conflict.

Comment: Beware that some delimiter characters (particularly `/` and `:`) have a special meaning in file/folder names and thus should be removed when putting a timestamp in a file or folder name.

Comment: Thank you very much @Noodles. Your solution is ingenious, however in this case the added character must be the same. I will bear this in mind for future however.

Comment: Thank you as well @AnsgarWiechers, I will make sure to take note of this for future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do what you want:

```
i = 0
If fso.FolderExists(filename) Then
  Do
    i = i + 1
    newname = filename & String(i, "a")
  Loop While fso.FolderExists(newname)
  filename = newname
End If
fso.CreateFolder(filename)
```

Personally I'd prefer a number suffix over a string of increasing length, though:

```
i = -1
If fso.FolderExists(filename) Then
  Do
    i = i + 1
    newname = filename & Right("000" & i, 3)
  Loop While fso.FolderExists(newname)
  filename = newname
End If
fso.CreateFolder(filename)
```

Or you could append a timestamp as @Noodles suggested in the comments to the question:

```
Function LPad(n) : LPad = Right("00" & n, 2) : End Function

timestamp = Year(Now) & LPad(Month(Now)) & LPad(Day(Now)) & LPad(Hour(Now)) & _
            LPad(Minute(Now)) & LPad(Second(Now))
fso.CreateFolder(filename & timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to create a temporary folder name, I usually do something like this:

```
Do
    strFolder = "c:\" & Left(fso.GetTempName(), 8)
Loop While fso.FolderExists(strFolder)
```

How does it work?

`GetTempName()` returns an 8.3 filename in the following format:

```
radXXXXX.tmp
```

where each `X` represents a random hexadecimal digit. So you can just extract the first 8 chars to use for your folder name (or  you can use the full name -- there's nothing stopping a folder from having an "extension"). Then just loop until you generate one that doesn't already exist.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific, but the file / files that I hope to create are not designed to be temporary. Thank you anyway, and this information will be helpful in future.

Comment: I probably should have used the word _arbitrary_ instead of _temporary_. The folders won't get removed automatically or anything. They'll just have arbitrary names.